# Generic interface for type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that returns a configuration, given an enum.
In my packages I'd like to create a `getConfiguration` method that would return me all the env variables that I need.

So for example :

```
enum PackageAEnvs {
   API_KEY = "API_KEY"
}

enum PackageBEnvs {
   ADMIN_URL = "ADMIN_URL"
}
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like this :

```
const getConfiguration = <T extends string[]> (conf: T): Record<T, string>{
     
  return conf.reduce( (acc, val) => {

    const env = process.env[val];

    if(! env) throw new Error()

    return { ...acc, [val]: env}

  }, {})

}
```

I would then like to have typescript raising errors if the key does not exist :

```
const { randomKey} = getConfiguration<PackageAEnvs>() <-- typescript should throw error
```

I found a way using a type :

```
type Conf = "K1" | "K2" 


type Config =  {[Property in  Conf]: string}

const getConfig = (): Config  => {

  return {
    K1: "2",
    K2: "2"
  }

}
const { someKey } = getConf() // <-- error
```

However how can I make this getConfig function generic so it could accept any type ?  Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to change your function to this:

```
const getConfiguration = <T extends object>(conf: T): Record<keyof T, string> => {
  return Object.keys(conf).reduce( (acc, val) => {
    const env = process.env[val];
    if(! env) throw new Error()
    return { ...acc, [val]: env}
  }, {}) as any
}
```

The function now takes the `enum` directly as an argument and constructs a `Record` where the keys are the enum keys. We also use `Object.keys(conf)` to get those keys at runtime.

```
const { API_KEY } = getConfiguration(PackageAEnvs)
const { ADMIN_URL } = getConfiguration(PackageBEnvs)
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgYwNZwObAIIFEQDcDOUA3gFBTkYwCSA%20gNJYCaUAvFAESW0OPskC%20JEqEixEKdACEcBYmQoARALJUAcjQCqAJQAyrDhmVrNuvoJIIA9iHwAXKOlsBhawDMAlqjAAnOLffW%20gA8ACpQwAAetqAAJoSWAEYAVsAItgB8ABRWIK4AXFAhAJQFWqmW3jFBSMAAnpauhQA0UHbe7iCo6azdpOTewLY%20IFAA8smptgB0NbX42W5FUwMxYAjAmVCZiAgtuHAANkU9cuTkOXbhePoADt6W6-j4U6C4ANr7BwC6ANzy5O5XJkAIRXXDHWwAC3uAHcoCBgHCsN57t5MkV-lABkNvCMiFApoSdi0PocvgVXoJyPwWkR%20Mc4IQ4CBagIhBd7PiuPQmFB%20PpHC5cp4fH4AiBMvBkGhMDJ8BiOcQoIYVOptHp%20WxBW4Rb5-NZJeIZdI8PKgA)